# How to access derived data from base class C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

class B :I'm in this type of scenario in my project, where I'm in `x()`function of base `class A` and need to access the data `y` from derived `class C`.
I have declared the object of derived `class C` and using `obj_c` i got to the `x()` function

```
class A
{
private :
    public :
    //.....
    void x()
    {
        cout << y ;
    }
    //.....
};

class B : public A
{
public :
    //.....
protected :
    //.....
private :
    //.....

};
class C : public B
{
public :
    //.....
protected :
    int y = 10 ;
private :

    //.....

};
int main()
{
    C obj_c ;
    obj_c.x();
}
```

Comment: You cannot do that without some weird hacks. Why not make `x()` `virtual` and `override` it in `C`?

Comment: Hint: `virtual`.

Comment: Check out [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: "*I'm in x()function of base class A and need to access the data y from derived class C.*" That's a contradiction in terms. `A` doesn't know if `C` even *exists*. Nor does it know if this current `A` is actually a `C`. Only `C` knows that it is a `C`.

Comment: What do you want to happen if somebody writes `B obj_b; obj_b.x();`?

Answer (score 0):

Place the declaration of y inside the base class. After all, the way you've written your code, A needs to contain a y in order to function.

The derived class can then assign the value by passing it up to A at construction.

```
class A {
public:
   void x() { cout << y; };

protected:
   A(int value) : y(value) {} 
   int y;
}

class B : public A
{
protected:
    B(int value) : A(value) {}
}

class C : public B
{
public:
    C() : B(10) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As C inherits from B and B inherits from A, then make function virtual in class. implement it in C and call it directly.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a base class is that `A` might be used even if `C` didn't exist. So where is `A` going to get `y`?

What you do in those cases is the [Template Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) design pattern:

`A` assumes that inheriting classes will provide a `y` by requiring that they implement a `get_y()` method:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    private :
    protected:
        virtual int get_y() = 0;
    public :
        //.....
        void x()
        {
            std::cout << get_y() << std::endl;
        }
        //.....
};

class B : public A
{
    public :
        //.....
    protected :
        //.....
    private :
        //.....

};
class C : public B
{
    public :
        //.....
    protected :
        int get_y()
        {
            return 10;
        }
    private :

        //.....

};
int main()
{
    C obj_c ;
    obj_c.x();
}
```